How to pass value from controller to view and display it in a text field or label
I am a bit stuck trying to figure out on how to show the value of a field model.SumValue which I am calculating in the controller class in a input field or a label.
Controller class -
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SumModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Sum(SumModel model)
{
   model.Sum= Sum();
   return View();
}

Model class -
public class SumModel
{
    public string SumValue { get; set; }
}

View class-
@model YourNamespace.SumModel
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>     
          <label>Sum Value:</label>     
          <input type="text" value="@Model.SumValue" readonly /> 
   </body> 
</html>

I am trying to set the field name this way into the <input/> field.
<input type="text" asp-for="SumValue" />
Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here?
Update - When I attempt to display the value it is taking me to a different page /Home/Sum and it says it cannot find the value.

Describe with details what exactly the problem you are faced is. Use the debugger to check the SumValue before rendering return View(model) and inspect the Model when entering the view. Also, use debugging console in a browser to check for any errors. Show more code: declaration of the data model, view data model declaration @model etc.

I am assuming you have used the Model in your view with respect to below code: `@model YourNamespace.YourModel





Sum Value:


`               Is this causing issues for you?
@Jackdaw - I have updated the code above. I have debugged it and can see value being set to model.SumValue but unable to display it in a input type field.

@hassaanmustafa - Yes, that is exactly how I am using it. Is there any issue with the way I have used it?

@Dazzler Correct me If i am wrong:
you have an index page where there is a readonly input field.
you want to display updated value of sumValue in that field on Index page?
OR
you want to take input of sumValue field on Index Page and show updated value of that field on /Home/Sum page?

You might be redirecting to another page because of your form submit URL. Please double check if the URL is same.

When passing to the view date model of type SumModel the same type should be declared in the view:
@model YourNamespace.SumModel
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>     
          <label>Sum Value:</label>     
          <input type="text" value="@Model.SumValue" readonly /> 
   </body> 
</html>

The @Model prefix might be omitted, because of the compiler construct attributes id and name using the model declaration used in the @model definition.
After you have updated your question we can see that the SumValue isn't  initialized. Try to define some value:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SumModel() { SumValue = "Test-Text"};
    return View(model);
}


Also, to check what is the HTML content is generated be Razor engine use mouse right click in the browser and select  View Page Source in the popup menu. This will help you to understand what HTML code is generated from your .cshtml and will give you more useful information.

Thank you. I am using the @model YourNamespace.SumModel at the top of the .cshtml class. I did not edit the code properly above in my question, apologies for the confusion. For some reason, I get a null reference when I try to use @Model.SumValue. Model is always null. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

@Dazzler: See my updated answer above. BTW, Model is null only if you doesn't pass any value when rendering the view by calling return View();. This means you enter the /Home/Sum URL in your browser.

Assuming you have to show the updated value on Index Page, in that case your code should look like:

Controller:

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SumModel();
    return View(Sum(model));
}

public SumModel Sum(SumModel model)
{
   model.SumValue= "100000";
   return model;
}

This will show value in your Read only field on your Index Page
In this case issue was that you were not passing updated SumValue value in model.
I hope this solves your issue


I am trying to set the field name this way into the  field.
Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here?

According to your shared code snippt, specifically at Index action method, you have simply initialized the model without any value. Which is:
    var model = new SumModel();
    return View(model);

So its basically empty. Becuase you haven't set any value into model property of SumValue. As a result in view you are getting nothing.
If you want to display a value in SumValue you should do as following:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SumModel();
    model.SumValue = "10.00";
    return View(model);
}

Now you would get value within your view:


On the other hand, you have also shared a POST method, which is not clear what you are trying to do here Becuase, you haven't shared what you are doing inside model.Sum = Sum();
If you are doing anything based on your posted value and then if you want that value to bind within your model in Index, You should return the value to the index action method. If you could share details of your Sum method, It can also be checked.
However, if you want to pass value from Post method to your index method then it will always be null. Becuase redirection from POST method to Index method will not keep the value which you have assigned  in your property.
Its due to the new instance of your model within the index method. You should use either global instance or tempData or anything which can retain the value while redirecting one method to another.
